# angularjs ui-router: Unknown provider: $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm having troubles using the ui-router plugin of AngularJS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
config(['$routeProvider', '$stateProvider', function($routeProvider, $stateProvider) {  
    $stateProvider
        .state('mandats', {
            url: '/domiciliations/mandats',
            templateUrl: 'domiciliations/views/mandats.html',
            controller: 'mandatsCtrl'
        });
}])
```

I then get this error at startup:

```
Unknown provider: $stateProvider
```

I've included the javascripts in this order:

```
<script src="/Scripts/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/libs/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/libs/angular/angular-ui-states.js"></script>
```

What could be the issue ?

**[EDIT]**

I've got rid of the error message by adding 'ui.compat' as a dependency of myApp. I saw that in the sample code of ui-router but nowhere in the documentation. What is this about ?

Nevertheless, it still does not work. I've added ui-view to a div in the application index file. But the page remains blank.

Comment: Can you  please list what version of Angular you are running?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following piece of code should do the job. At least in my case, so let me know if it works or not.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.compat']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$stateProvider', function($routeProvider, $stateProvider) {  
    $stateProvider
        .state('mandats', {
            url: '/domiciliations/mandats',
            templateUrl: 'domiciliations/views/mandats.html',
            controller: 'mandatsCtrl'
        });
}])
```

Now about your issue with the page being empty. For sure the URL you have in the browser is not matched with any defined in your state. Try this '#/domiciliations/mandats' in your browser and see if the view gets rendered appropriately. Not that you absolute url should be something similar with **http://[HOST_NAME]/home.html#/domiciliations/mandats**.

Comment: like I said in my previous reply, that's what I ended up doing. I'll mark your reply as  answer though ;) Thanks.

Comment: I tried this and angular could not fin 'ui-compat'; error below
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.compat due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.compat' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 15):

You just need to include ui-router module as dependency.

like following

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ["ui.router"])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$stateProvider', function($routeProvider, $stateProvider) { 
        ...
    }]);
```

Comment: Where are you closing your array in `.config`?

Answer (score 3):

Including the [angular-ui v0.0.2](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/build/angular-ui-router.js) will fix the problem.